# Cannot apply BigDecimal to constructor

Tags: java, java-8

**I have object like:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class Obj {
    BigDecimal Sal;
    int EMPID;

    public Obj(BigDecimal Sal, int EMPID) {
        this.Sal= Sal;
        this.EMPID= EMPID;
    }
}
```

Now I wanna create Instance of Obj with constructor call.

```
Obj a = new Obj(45,34); // getting error here
```

Tried this also: `Obj a = new Obj( (BigDecimal) 45,34);`

Error:

> Obj (java.math.BigDecimal, int) in Obj cannot be applied to (int, int)

Comment: `45` is not a `BigDecimal`. Use either `new Obj(BigDecimal.valueOf(45), 34)`, `new Obj(new BigDecimal("45"), 34)` or `new Obj(new BigDecimal(45), 34)`

Comment: As an aside, even though EMPID is in uppercase in the real world, let Java code conventions win in Java: use `empId` or `empid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is a class and you need to create an instance of it.
Do: `Obj a = new Obj(new BigDecimal(45), 34)`

Comment: `BigDecimal` is not a *Object* but a **class**.

Comment: I was aiming at what data type it is, i.e. objects vs primitives. Of course the name itself is a class and an instance of that class is an object, I thought that that was obvious. However I understand the need to be precise so that someone else might not get confused by the nomenclature.